# Installing lxml without pip

Tags: python, xml, linux, lxml, sudo

Hello internet strangers,

I need to do XSD verification with lxml, but do not have sudo abilities on the machine I'm using - so pip is not an option. I'm on Fedora 27 and found the source code for lxml, which requires:

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev

But I cant use sudo on the machine I'm deploying to. Once I have those dependencies all I need to do is get the lxml source code through wget or github, and then run setup.py install, but I cant do that if I cant install the above dependencies.

Help?

Useful links:

https://gist.github.com/blite/868292

https://github.com/lxml/lxml

Comment: You don't need privileges in order to install software with `pip`.  Read up on the `--user` option, or possibly learn about Python virtual environments.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the info! Just for clarification the problem with pip is that any pip install *somepackage_v4.2* needs to be version controlled. If another developer comes along and needs *somepackage_4.4* in this case venv is the proper solution.

There is still the problem of how to get sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev without sudo (cant find that install option in pip)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into creating a virtual environment and installing dependencies there.  Here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/venv.html

Basically you create a virtual environment like this:

```
$ python -m venv my_venv_name
```

That creates a folder call my_venv_name with a few folders under it (do this somewhere in your home directory). The issue the command

```
$ source my_venv_name/bin/activate
```

That activates your environment.  At this point you can pip install into your virtual environment to your hearts content.  You just need to remember to activate the environment for each session that you want to use it in.

Comment: What about the required libraries of yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel? I can't find virtualized install commands for those with pip or venv in my virtual enviroment?

Comment: Looks like you can get libxml2 here http://www.xmlsoft.org/downloads.html and libxslt here http://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/downloads.html.